# Sum of $a_0+a_1+\cdots + a_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

If $a_0=2 , a_1=5 $and for $n>1 $
$$a_n=5a_{n-1}-6a_{n-2}$$

then

$$a_0+a_1+\cdots+a_n=?$$

I know telescoping series but

$$a_n=5(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})-a_{n-2}$$

Thanks for your help.

Mani

Comment: There are rational constants $B,C$ such that $a_n = B 2^n  + C 3^n.$ You need to find $B,C$ and continue

Comment: Welcome to this site!  Please refer to the following link on how to format your math:  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Did you meant to say that $a_1=5$ instead of $a_n=5$?

Comment: @Mani: I and others  tried to edit it for you, but you keep changing it stubbornly back to the raw format.

Comment: @DeepSea XD Think its good now.  Hopefully he got the $\LaTeX$ basics.

Comment: What means negative point. I tried to type my question correctly

Comment: @Mani There is a reputation system on this site.  If someone thinks this question was poorly made, the question has little context, you have put in little effort, or some other reason, they will downvote you, which constitutes negative rep.  If someone thinks you did a good job, you will gain rep.  Rep is used for various things, like showing you are good on this site and priveleges.

Comment: Finally I learn it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$, we have
 $$6x^2F(x)=6\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^{n+2}$$
 $$5xF(x)=5\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^{n+1}$$
therefore
 $$(1-5x+6x^2)F(x)=a_0+(a_1-5a_0)x$$
in other words
$$F(x)=\frac{2-5x}{(1-2x)(1-3x)}=\frac{1}{1-2x}+\frac{1}{1-3x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2x)^n+(3x)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2^n+3^n)x^n$$
thus
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i=\sum_{i=0}^{n}(2^i+3^i)=\frac{2^{n+2}+3^{n+1}-3}{2}$$

Comment: $F(x)$=????????

Comment: Generating function.

Comment: Please check it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function

Comment: F (x) and the variable x were invented for this answer.  Set x=1 and F(1)= the sum we want to evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly
$$ a_n-2a_{n-1}=3(a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2}). $$
So
$$ a_n-2a_{n-1}=3^{n-1}(a_{1}-2a_{0})=3^{n-1}. \tag{1}$$
Similarly
$$ a_n-3a_{n-1}=2^{n-1}(a_{1}-2a_{0})=-2^{n-1}. \tag{2}$$
(1)(2) give
$$ a_n=3^n+2^n.$$
So
$$ a_0+a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n=(1+3+3^2+\cdots+3^n)+(1+2+2^2+\cdots+3^n)=\frac12\cdot(3^{n+1}-1)+(2^{n+1}-1).$$

Comment: @Barry Cipra, thanks.